# Nodejs make an array and print it outside of loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wanted to make an array based on query results from mongodb, after created the array I can not print this outside of for loop here is the code

```
    let results = await model.find({status: 'active'});
    let finalResult = [];

     results.forEach( async result=> {
      let fromDate = new Date(result.validFrom);
      query = {
       createdAt: {
        $gte: fromDate.getTime(),
        $lte: toDate.getTime(),
       }
      }

       results1 = await model1.find(query);
         results1.forEach(result1=> {
          finalResult.push(result1);
        })
      
   });

   console.log(finalResult);
```

I am getting an empty array for finalResult log. can you please help me for this?

Comment: you missed the closing bracket of `query` object variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Use `for...of` and the question above to figure out how to return a value from an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for...of` instead of `forEach`. `forEach` recipes a callback function as a parameter, and it not support async function.

```js
const results = await model.find({ status: 'active' });
const finalResult = [];

for (const result of results) {
  let fromDate = new Date(result.validFrom);
  query = {
     createdAt: {
        $gte: fromDate.getTime(),
        $lte: toDate.getTime(),
     }
  };
  const items = await model1.find(query);
  finalResult.push(...items);
}

console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: you not used the query variable, can you please use query variable as I used?

Comment: @mdkamrul Updated. But why?

Comment: because I have used this var at other place

Comment: how can I use results object at loop?

Comment: Do you mean `results` 's element? just change `_` to what you want.

Comment: I have edited my question please check, so I want to use results object at loop

Comment: yes its working fine now, thanks for you solution

Comment: is there any solution to omit query in loop? this will harm performance

Comment: Try to get minimum and maximum of `createdAt` and take one query. re-filter by js code.

Comment: can you please another solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` with `async` doesn't work as expected. `forEach` don't wait for asynchronous calls. Better use `map` or `for...of` loops.

Using `for...of` is `serial`, Using `map & Promise.all` is parallel,

```
const results = await model.find({ status: 'active' });

const resultMap = results.map(async result =>  await model1.find({
    createdAt: {
      $gte: fromDate.getTime(),
      $lte: toDate.getTime(),
    }
  })
)

Promise.all(resultMap).then((data) => {
  console.log(data); // You might need one more loop here for finalData
})
```